Retrieve data from Excel whose values are formulated
I am trying to read excel which is formulated means some values in excel is driven from formula I have tried two approach but I don't receive any value. I get 'None'. Can someone of you review my code and help me please?
I have tried two approaches and no clue. I wish to read data in same way as shown in excel
def clean_data_from_excel(self,file_path)
# Load the workbook and select the sheet
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path,data_only=True)
        sheet = wb['ABC']
         row_num = sheet.max_row  # Number of rows
         col_num = sheet.max_column  # Number of columns
        
         all_rows = []
         # Loop through rows and columns
         for row in range(2, row_num + 1):  # Skip header row
             row_values = {}
             for column in range(1, col_num + 1):
                 # Get cell element
                 cell = sheet.cell(row=row, column=column)
                 header = sheet.cell(row=1, column=column).value  # Get header for keys
                 row_values[header] = cell.value  # Store value exactly as it is in the cell
        
             if row_values:
                 all_rows.append(row_values)

        return all_rows 

Another approach
        data_section1 = []

        for row in sheet['A2:B15']:
            row_data = [cell.value for cell in row]
            print("row_data -----> ", row_data)
            data_section1.append(row_data)

        print("data_section1 -----> ", data_section1)

        data_dict = {item[0]: [item[1]] for item in data_section1}
        print("data_dict -----> ", data_dict)
        # Create DataFrame
        df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)

        print("data_df -----> ", df)


If you want formulas and not the evaluated value, then don't use data_only=True Otherwise, ignoring the incorrect indenting, your code would iterate the cells in the 'used range' and get the values in the cell. If you are getting None then check what cells you are iterating over and you can print it's value as you go.

It did not work when removed data_only=True @moken is anything you suspect?

It did not work doesn't tell me much. However as noted in the previous comment, whether you have data_only= set to True or False you will either get the Cell Value or the Cell Formula. If you are getting None then you reading a blank/empty cell so are you actually iterating the cells where your data exists?
